# Font lost when simulating on iPad

Tags: ios, ipad, fonts, storyboard

I have a label in my app that works in all screen sizes. The text uses a custom font. So far so good.

When I run the app on an iPad the text becomes too small so I created a font size that only applies to regular height regular width. This looks fine in the storyboard but when I simulate as an iPad it loses the font and size. This does not happened when I use another font.

I have cleared and restarted Xcode. I made sure the font is in `Info.plist` and that the project is selected in Target membership.

What could be wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Choose **System Font** in storyboard for size classes.
Change your Font in code.

[image]

```
self.yourLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Custom regular Font" size:self.yourLabel.font.pointSize];
```

This is sort of a bug in size classes.

Comment: Beautiful! I put the code in viewDidappear (for some reason it doesn't work putting it in viewdidload) But when I rotate the screen it resets the font to system.

Comment: try adding this in viewDidLayoutSubViews. If it work for you than don't forget to accept it. Thanks

Comment: Thank you Irfan. I really appreciate your help!